# Вызовет ли realloc утечку памяти?

Tags: c, утечка-памяти, realloc

Доброго времени суток! Есть код:

```
// mry_char*  - это wchar_t*
// mry_charsz - это sizeof(wchar_t)

void mry_strcat(mry_char* _dest, const mry_char const* _src) {
    const u32 dl = mry_strlen(_dest);
    const u32 sl = mry_strlen(_src);

    _dest = realloc(_dest, (dl + sl + 1) * mry_charsz);
    memmove(_dest + dl, _src, sl * mry_charsz);
    _dest[dl + sl] = '\0';
}
```

*Cppcheck* пишет:

```
Id: memleak
Кратко: Memory leak: _dest
Сообщение: Memory leak: _dest

First included by: mary.c

Строка 69: _dest[dl + sl] = '\0';
```

Я так понимаю, что утечка будет, если `realloc` переместит блок при возрастании размера, так ли это?

**UPD**

Исправил выход за границы массива.

Comment: Так а почему памяти выделяется только `dl + sl`, если потом делается `_dest[dl + sl] = '\0'`? Явный вылет за пределы выделенной памяти.

Comment: 1) В общем случае - *так* применять `realloc()` нельзя. О чём явно написано в описании этой функции, например, в мане. 2) Классика - забыли один байт для завершающего `\0`

Comment: @Eanmos: ??? Выход за пределы массива у вас "исправлен" неправильно. Ваше "исправление выхода за пределы массива" явно демонстрирует, что вы вообще не понимаете, что здесь к чему. Это вообще ваш код?

Comment: @AnT, мой, мой :) "*что вы вообще не понимаете, что здесь к чему*", понимаю, действительно, не все, по этому и задал вопрос. Нужно вместо `1` прибавлять `mry_charsz`?

Comment: @Eanmos: Либо прибавлять `mry_charsz`, либо прибавлять 1 до умножения `(dl + sl + 1) * mry_charsz`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В своем коде вы должны рассчитывать на то, что `realloc` будет *всегда* перемещать блок, независимо от того, увеличивается ли его размер, уменьшается ли или вообще не меняется. Эти решения принимаются на основе неподконтрольных вам обстоятельств. То, что он может иногда и не переместиться - не более чем редкая и непредсказуемая удача.

Утечка у вас образуется из-за того, что новое значение указателя `_dest` в наружный код никак не возвращается. Память, выделенная вашим `realloc` в общем случае становится утечкой всегда. Либо возвращайте новый `_dest` из функции через возвращаемое значение, либо работайте с ним "по ссылке", т.е. делайте его `mry_char**` параметром.

(Да, если в результате работы `realloc` значение указателя `_dest` не изменилось, то формально возвращать его "не нужно", но ожидать этого в реальном коде - это полная белиберда. В общем случае значение указателя будет меняться.)

Дополнительно, в связи *именно* c `realloc` утечка также может возникнуть, если `realloc` не сможет выделить память вообще. Тогда он вернет null-указатель, но старую память не освободит, т.е. внутри функции доступ к памяти, изначально указываемой `_dest`, вы потеряете. (Будет ли это полноценной утечкой зависит от того, сохранили ли вы еще какой-то путь доступа к этой памяти. Из вашего кода этого не видно.)

Также, почему памяти выделяется только под `dl + sl` элементов, если потом делается `_dest[dl + sl] = '\0'`? Явный вылет за пределы выделенной памяти.

Comment: "*... новое значение _dest в наружный код никак не возвращается*", почему? Я ведь изменяю входящую строку.

Comment: @Eanmos: Я говорю именно о новом значении указателя `_dest`, а не строки, на которую он указывает. Каким образом вызывающий код получит новое значение указателя `_dest`???

Comment: `_dest` - это указатель, `realloc` возвращает указатель, получается, что при `_dest = realloc(...)`, `_dest` получает новый адрес, разве нет?

Comment: @Eanmos: Да, верно. Указатель `_dest` получает новое значение - он будет содержать новый адрес (адрес нового блока памяти). Но вы этот новый адрес никуда никому не передаете. Он просто теряется навсегда, когда переменная `_dest` исчезает при завершении функции `mry_strcat`.

Comment: Так ведь мне и нужно, чтобы `_dest` получила новое значение. А кому еще нужно передавать адрес? Вы уж извините, если туплю, но что-то я запутался :)

Comment: @Eanmos: Как это "кому"? Наружному коду! У вас снаружи был сделан некий вызов `mry_strcat(a, b)`, где `a` и `b` - указатели. После вызова `mry_strcat(a, b)` блок памяти (изначально указывавшийся `a`) расширился и переместился куда-то в новое место. Но значение `a` ведь не поменялось! `a` по прежнему указывает в "старое" место (где уже ничего нет). А новое положение блока памяти в наружный код никак не передано. Никто не знает, где он располагается. Это и есть утечка памяти.

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно в самом начале функции создать переменную `mry_char* ptr = _dest;`, а в конце вызвать `free(_ptr)`? Но в таком случае, если блок не переместиться, то освободиться и `_dest`.

Comment: @Eanmos: Нет. Что такое `free(_ptr)` и при чем это здесь я не знаю. Я уже написал вам: вы должны передать новое значение `_dest` обратно в вызывающий код.

Answer (score 3):

Утечки как таковой **из-за `realloc`** не появляется - если вы не забудете потом удалить выделенную память.

Другое дело, что вы
1. не проверяете результат `realloc` (и  не сохраняете его)
2. выделяете недостаточно памяти (есть выход за границу)
3. Насколько я помню, для `wchar_t` надо записывать не `'\0'`, а `L'\0'`

Comment: И `'\0'` и `L'\0'` - это не более чем целочисленная константа `0`. С точки зрения элегантности кода `L'\0'` было бы более уместно, но разницы никакой нет. Можно вообще использовать просто `0`.